# Logout out of all devices for a Google account

Tags: security, google-account, logout

I want to force logout on all devices signed into my Google account. I don't actually use Gmail with this account, I use it for primarily for Drive and Calendar.

Recently I've logged into a few third party machines. Although I logged out and have 2-step authentication set up, I would feel happier if I could force logout remotely just to be doubly sure, as with 2 step auth you can click 'remember this computer for 30 days'.

Is there also a way to see all logged in devices/sessions in a similar way to how Dropbox shows you (e.g. Computer Name, Location, Most recent activity).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Recent Activity](https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity) page shows the last 20 or so logins, with location, client, and OS.

Their advice on that page, if you notice "unusual activity", is to change your password.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here:  https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens

and if you login to gmail, you can see your (mail) account activity + detail-link in the bottom right corner ('detail' is a link)

> Last account activity: 19 minutes ago
>   Detail

Comment: Thanks, but those auth sub tokens, relate to were you are using your account to login to another service, rather than actual logins to the account, correct ?

Comment: You are correct, a but the 'detail' link directs you to active sessions (logins), did you check that as well?

Comment: No i couldnt see the detail link, were on the page is it ?

Comment: Like I said. Log in to gmail and look at the bottom right corner. I can't be more clear than that. So eeuhm.. scroll down. And then to the right. ..

Comment: sorry i thought you were still talking about the /IssuedAuthSubTokens page, as i said in the question this account doesnt have a gmail address associated with it..

Comment: I interpreted as "not use" as "not use", not as "can not log in", but this is all you get. You could go to you account page and check you activity, but you can only change your password there.